# Product could not be found - Nested Line Items

Tags: php, shopware, shopware6

I've got this function in a custom controller:

```php
public function addLineItems(Cart $cart, RequestDataBag $requestDataBag, Request $request, SalesChannelContext $context): Response
{
    $lineItemIds = $requestDataBag->get('lineItems');
    $containerLineItem = new LineItem('bundle', LineItem::PRODUCT_LINE_ITEM_TYPE, '', 1);

    $lineItemsArray = [];
    foreach ($lineItemIds as $id => $lineItemBag) {
        if ($lineItemBag instanceof RequestDataBag && $lineItemBag->has('id')) {
            $productId = $lineItemBag->get('id');
            $lineItemsArray[] = $this->getLineItem($productId);
        }
    }

    $nestedLineItems = new LineItemCollection($lineItemsArray);

    $containerLineItem->setChildren($nestedLineItems);

    $cart = $this->cartService->getCart($context->getToken(), $context);
    $cart->add($containerLineItem);

    $this->cartPersister->save($cart, $context);
    return $this->createActionResponse($request);
```

When I add a product to the cart I see the error message "Product could not be found". First I thought it was because "bundle" in $containerLineItem doesn't exists, so I tried to add a product ID of an existing product. But then the problem still exist.

What I try to achieve is add multiple products to the cart as a bundle. In theory the bundle doesn't exist, so it's just a virtual container to wrap the items.

I also found out that if I dump $nestedLineItems then I can see the products with the ID's, but all the other information like payload, price, description, cover etc... isn't there.

What do I need to change to get these two problems working and is there something else I can improve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
public function addLineItems(Cart $cart, RequestDataBag $requestDataBag, Request $request, SalesChannelContext $context): Response
    {
        $lineItemIds = $requestDataBag->get('lineItems');
        $containerLineItemId = Uuid::randomHex();
        $containerLineItem = new LineItem($containerLineItemId, LineItem::CONTAINER_LINE_ITEM, $containerLineItemId, 1);

        // Make the lineItem stackable
        $containerLineItem->setStackable(true);

        // Make the lineItem removable
        $containerLineItem->setRemovable(true);

        $lineItemsArray = [];
        foreach ($lineItemIds as $id => $lineItemBag) {
            if ($lineItemBag instanceof RequestDataBag) {
                $productId = $lineItemBag->get('id');
                $lineItemsArray[] = $this->getLineItem($productId);
            }
        }

        $nestedLineItems = new LineItemCollection($lineItemsArray);

        $containerLineItem->setChildren($nestedLineItems);

        $cart = $this->cartService->getCart($context->getToken(), $context);
        $cart->add($containerLineItem);

        $this->cartPersister->save($cart, $context);
        return $this->createActionResponse($request);
    }
```

After some trial and error I've got it working. I'm generating an ID and save it as variable ($containerLineItemId). This is used in $containerLineItem. And instead of using PRODUCT_LINE_ITEM_TYPE I'm using CONTAINER_LINE_ITEM to bundle all the items.