# Nested LineItems not showing in admin

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I’ve created Nested LineItems and they are wrapped in a container. See this topic for my code: [Product could not be found - Nested Line Items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77016740/product-could-not-be-found-nested-line-items)

Now when I place an order I can see the container lineItem on the order view in the admin. But the nested lineItems (the child products) aren’t showing.

What can be the problem and how can I fix this?